# Linear approximation of exponential for the $L^1$ norm. Find $a,b$ that minimize $||ax+b-e^x||_{1}$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Define the norm $\displaystyle ||f||_{1}=\int_{a}^{b} |f(x)| dx\ $ which is the $ L^{1}  $ norm.

Find the linear function $ l(x)=a_{0}+a_{1}x\ $ that minimizes $ ||e^{x}-l(x)||_{1} $ in the interval $ [-1,1] $.

**Answer::** Here least square principlle is applicable since the norm $||.||_{1} $ is not induced by any inner product. **That is why I got stuck. Any Idea or little help doing this is appreciating .**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem seems difficult because when we have a look at the graph of $e^x$ and $l(x)=a_1x+a_0$ in the area of interest (around $a_0,a_1\simeq 1$).

We notice that there are $2$ intersections at $-1\le x_1\le x_2\le 1$ between the curves (exponential in blue, and linear approximation in green).

[image]

So overall the absolute value of the difference is small and minimize $||\cdot||_1$

Let's have a look at the area under the curves of $|e^x-l(x)|$

Numerical solving approach gives $l(x)=1.042x+1.128$ for $I\simeq0.266$ as a minimum (blue curve).

This is better than Taylor approximation in zero, $l(x)=x+1$ which gives $I\simeq 0.3504$ (red curve).

[image]

Indeed we can visualize that the Taylor approximation has a lower value near $0$ but the area under the curve raises at the bounds of the interval, while with the $L^1$ approximation we lose a bit in the middle but gain it back at the bounds.

Interestingly enough, $x_1$ and $x_2$ seem super simple in that case, with value $\pm\frac 12$.

Assuming this result, we can give a theoretical value for $a_0$ and $a_1$.

$\begin{cases}
x_1=-0.5 & \frac 1{\sqrt{e}}=-\frac {a_1}2+a_0\\
x_2=+0.5 & \sqrt{e}=\frac {a_1}2+a_0\\
\end{cases}\implies$

> $$l(x)=2x\sinh\big(\frac 12\big)+\cosh\big(\frac 12\big)$$

---

If we would know these points $x_1$ and $x_2$ of $[-1,1]$ then calculating the norm is long but not too difficult :

$$I=||e^x-l(x)||_1=\int_{-1}^{x_1}(e^x-a_1x-a_0)dx-\int_{x_1}^{x_2}(e^x-a_1x-a_0)dx+\int_{x_2}^{1}(e^x-a_1x-a_0)dx$$

Let's parametrize $a_0,a_1$ in function of the intersection points.

We have $\displaystyle a_1=\frac{e^{x_2}-e^{x_1}}{x_2-x_1}\quad\text{and}\quad a_0=\frac{x_2e^{x_1}-x_1e^{x_2}}{x_2-x_1}$

At this point the calculations are a bit tedious, so I'll use symbolic calculation software and manual simplification and give you the result :

$$I=(e-\frac 1e)+\frac {4x_1e^{x_2}-2x_1e^{x_1}-2x_2e^{x_2}+(x_1-x_2)^2(e^{x_1}+e^{x_2})}{x_2-x_1}$$

To find the minimum, let's calculate the partial derivatives :

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial I}{\partial x_1}=\frac{\big((x_2-x_1)^2-2x_2\big)\big((x_2-x_1)e^{x_1}+e^{x_1}-e^{x_2}\big)}{(x_2-x_1)^2}$

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial I}{\partial x_2}=\frac{\big((x_2-x_1)^2+2x_1\big)\big((x_2-x_1)e^{x_2}+e^{x_1}-e^{x_2}\big)}{(x_2-x_1)^2}$

It's a bit difficult to notice but the second factor is always of constant sign.

Let's rewrite it using $u=(x_2-x_1)$.

$e^{x_1}(x_2-x_1)+e^{x_1}-e^{x_2}=e^{x_1}u+e^{x_1}-e^{x_1+u}=e^{x_1}\underbrace{(u+1-e^u)}_{\le 0}\le 0$

This is the same for the other derivative, the only possibility of annulation is the case $u=0$.

---

$u=0$ implies $x_1=x_2$ so we consider the local minimum for all tangential lines.

In this case $I(x,x+u)=e-\frac 1e+2xe^x-2e^x+O(u)$

This is minimized for $x=0$ with value $e-\frac 1e-2\simeq 0.35\ $ which as we already saw is not the global minimum for $I$.

In fact this case corresponds to the Taylor approximation $l(x)=1+x$ that we have already examined. This side study shows that he Taylor approximation minimizes the $L^1$ norm for all tangents in $[-1,1]$.

---

So coming back to our partial derivatives, the remaining case is to annulate the first factor.

$\begin{cases} (x_2-x_1)^2-2x_2=0\\ (x_2-x_1)^2+2x_1=0 \end{cases}\iff
\begin{cases} x_2=-x_1\\ 4x_2^2-2x_2=0 \end{cases}$

According to the condition $x_1\le x_2$ this gives $x_1=-\frac 12,\ x_2=\frac 12$

And we have proved the result exposed in the first part.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** try for $l$ the first order Taylor polynomial of $e^x$, i.e. $l(x)=1+x$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the minimum of $||f||_1$ is zero for any real valued functional $f$. Let's evaluate this:
$$\int_{-1}^1|e^x-l(x)|\,dx\geq\left|\int_{-1}^1(e^x-a_0-a_1x)\,dx\right|=\left|e-e^{-1}-2a_0-\frac{a_1}{2}+\frac{a_1}{2}\right|=0$$
$$\implies a_0=\frac{e-e^{-1}}{2}$$
Notice it does not matter the choice for $a_1$ as it disappears on integration. This would be considered to be a "free variable". Keep in mind this result is a consequence of the interval and the harmonic function $l(x)$.