# Minimisation of integral including absolute values

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, maxima-minima

I need to solve the following

$$\min_{c,d} \int_0^1 |ct+d-t^2| dt.$$

Since the integrand is of degree two, I considered to split the integral in three. My problem however, is that the bounds would then depend on $c$ as well as $d$. Is there any extension of the Leibnitz integral rule (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) that lets you deal with two parameters in the bound?

Comment: Your polynomial factorizes as $(t-a_0)(t-a_1)$ and you know the sign on intervals $]-\infty,a_0[,[a_0,a_1],]a_1,+\infty[$ so you can decompose the integral in parts without absolute value. I did something similar here for $\exp$ instead of $t^2$. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344512/linear-approximation-of-exponential-for-the-l1-norm-find-a-b-that-minimize/2346260#2346260. Notice that because of minimization request, $a_0$ and $a_1$  are inside $[0,1]$

Comment: Could you elaborate om why $a_0, a_1 \in [0,1]$?

Comment: Look at the graph  in the post I linked. You have to minimize the area between the curve and a line. Since $t^2$ is convex you can achieve that only when the line cuts the curve inside $[0,1]$ else this would just be a big belly contributing a lot to the result. With a cross, the area is spread on both sides off $y=t^2$ and the sum is minimized.

Comment: I am just trying to find a formal (mathematical) argument instead of a pictorial argument.